# Server side paging for gridview in a Sharepoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint, gridview, datatable

I have custom some controls residing in **SharepPoint** webparts.  I use a **GridView** control to take advantage of the built-in paging and column sort.  The **GridView** gets databound from a method that iterates through an `SPlist` (with a **`foreach`** loop) to build a **DataTable**.  This looping through the list is required to apply logic to process the list prior to display in the grid.

As the list get bigger, the page takes longer (forever) to load.  Even though the paging permits the **GridView** to display only 12 rows of data, I believe the `foreach` loop is processing the entire list.

I've done server-side paging in .Net with both SQL and nHibernate.  It should be possible to do this in **SharePoint**, right?. I am looking for some guidence, sample code, or any type of direction.  Even a definitive "you're an idiot"  would help.

Anyone done this before?  Or, does anyone have an alternative databind scheam that they could suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: The reason the page takes longer to load is because it is paging in memory,so the more memory you take up(the bigger the list) the longer it will take.

Answer (score 2):

If its possible to get the data using an SPQuery you can use the RowLimit and ListItemCollectionPosition properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollectionposition.aspx

http://www.zimbio.com/SQL/articles/625/Paging+SPList+Sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Paging under SharePoint is fundamentally the same as in ASP.NET and if there is a speed difference I would attribute it to your SharePoint datasource, rather than just the fact that the gridview is running in SharePoint.

Are you databinding more than you need to?

You could possibly cache your data in the Page.Cache object and destroy the cache copy whenever something like a delete or update dirties the data.